# ArcPY Set Current MXD to Full Extent

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

Can you please let me know how we can set current map to Full Extent [image] using ESRI ArcPy?

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping

# Set the Map to be Full Extent

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.Set-To-Full_Extent
```

like what the [image] is doing on main toolbar

[image]

in the ArcMap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "MyDataframeName")[0]
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

If you leave the parentheses empty, it zooms to full extent by default.

If you only have a single dataframe you can simplify line 2 to:

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
```

Read this [help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm) for further details.

Comment: Thanks Joechoj but I am getting this error `Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What are the contents of line 5?

Comment: `df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "MyDataframeName")[0]`